# How do I do base64 encoding in LibSass?

Tags: sass, libsass

I have a bunch of SVGs that get color and parameter adaptations in Sass and then when called to be background-image. That's done using something like:

```
this @function(@params) dostuff..
    @return url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ base64_encode($svg));
```

The `base64_encode` function is ruby but with ever growing Sass we're looking at switching to LibSass but i have so far been unable to get base64 encoding to work with LibSass. How do i get base64 encoding in LibSass?

Comment: If you're using the ruby implementation of LibSass, you can just continue to use the ruby function.

Comment: Were using ruby sass now but the waits between editing scss and seeing results are getting frustratingly long.  This is why we are considering moving to libsass,  the c implementation of the sass compiler

Comment: LibSass is just a library. Perhaps you mean SassC? In that case, use a library like [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I added a base64-encode() function directly to libsass as proof of concept: https://github.com/jonasjonas/libsass/commit/3a82437e267bdfc942799f0f14e1672013ba1acc

Comment: Yepp, that's more or less precisely what i ended up doing but I did it  as an extra preprocessing step instead.